# Stuck at "Retracting buffer" after type class resolution diverges

Tags: coq

When using typeclasses, Coq sometimes diverges.  When this happens under Proof General, Emacs also hangs.

The best way I know to recover is to interrupt emacs (C-g) and restart Coq (C-c C-x).  But, instead of just killing the Coq process, this puts me in a mode where Emacs is again hung, displaying "Retracting buffer..." for a quite long time (sometimes so long that I give up and just start a whole new emacs!).

Why?

Is there a better way?  (And: Is there an easy first step for viewing what is diverging in the first place when this happens?)

Answer (score 2):

If emacs is hung on anything other than garbage collection, you can generally interrupt it with `C-g`.  If `C-c C-x` / `C-c C-c` don't work, you can kill the coqtop process from process manager / from the command line with `pkill coqtop`.

This happens because coqtop has some loops where it does not check for interrupt, or does not check often enough, and so it does not catch the interrupt from PG in a timely manner.

Additionally, as mentioned in other answers, `Set Typeclasses Debug` will give you a very verbose log of typeclass resolution in the `*response*` and `*coq*` buffers.

Comment: Thanks -- that's useful to know.  Further experience shows that C-c C-x _doesl_ eventually work, but sometimes it takes quite a while.

Comment: I think `C-c C-x` waits until Coq finishes processing a statement before restarting Coq, while `C-c C-c` sends Coq an interrupt.  I generally alternate between spamming `C-c C-c` and `C-g`, and sometimes give up on that and `pkill coqtop`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this actually does anything, but sometimes I find that Proof General interrupts Coq if I press `C-c C-c` a few times.

As for your second question, you can add `Set Typeclasses Debug.` to your script before invoking the problematic line. Then Coq will print a trace of its instance search in the `*response*` buffer in Emacs. If your script is looping, make sure you hit `C-c C-c` right after triggering the loop, as the trace can get very long quite fast

Answer (score 0):

For the last bit, I reminded myself of

> Set Typeclasses Debug.

Answer (score 0):

Strange: I'm not actually sure any more whether emacs is stuck at the end or whether it's a display bug: it seems that if I switch to another screen and then switch back I find the *coq exited* message that I expect, right away.